# Destructor called to destruct object before I finish using this object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, shallow-copy

In my code there's operator+ overloading. In this scope, I define object `ans`, which I want to build and return, but it seems that the destructor distructs `ans` before I can return it, so this method returns some undefined value.

I don't understand where I am wrong? Is it the destructor, the builder, or in my overload of the operator+?

Here is my code:

```
class vector1{
    int * arr;
int size;
public:
//constructors
vector1(){}
vector1(int n){
    size=n;
    arr= new int[size];
}
//functions
int get_size(){return size;}

void init(){  //initialize all array cells to 0
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        arr[i]=0;
}
int get_value_in_index(int index){
    return arr[index];
}
void set_value_in_index(int i, int num){
    arr[i]=num;
}
int & operator[](int i){
    int default_val=0;
    if (i<0 || i>size){
        cout<<"index not valid"<<endl;
        return default_val;
    }
    return arr[i];
}
vector1 operator+(vector1 & ob);

//destructor
~vector1(){
    delete [] arr;
}
};

vector1 vector1:: operator+(vector1 & ob){
vector1 ans(size);
if (ob.get_size()!=size){  //if the arrays are not the same size return array of     '0', this array size
    cout<<"vectors not the same length. can't sum them"<<endl;
    //test
    //exit(1);
    ans.init();
}
else{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        ans.set_value_in_index(i,arr[i]+ob.get_value_in_index(i));
}
return ans;
}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You're violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) there cupcake.

Answer (score 5):

Your operator+ returns a copy of a new `vector1` class.
But the original (the one declared in the beginning of the function) gets destroyed at the end of the block (before the closing bracket **}**).

The destructor then deletes the inner array `arr`.
So the copied `vector1` object points to a deleted array.

You should create a copy constructor that will copy the inner array as well.

```
vector1(const vector1& _other ){
 //copy .arr from the other one to this one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return from `operator+` a shallow copy of `ans` is made leaving two instances of `vector1` pointing to the same data. When the first instance goes out of scope it deletes the data that both point to. To correct this you need to add a copy constructor that makes deep copies to `vector1`

```
vector1(const vector1& other)
{
    // make a deep copy from "other.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define a copy constructor so a default one was created by the compiler.

your `operator+` returns a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) of your vector.
when `ans` goes out of scope at the end of the operator it takes the data with him.

please read more about [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)